# Auto populate table with date With Date

Tags: vba, input, fetch

I am Trying to scape a web table through vba In excel, But the table isn't populating, i would appreciate if someone helps. Thanks.
Below is my code:

```
Dim strdate As String
Dim eddate As String
Dim obj As Object

Set objie = New InternetExplorer
objie.Visible = True
objie.navigate "https://www.khistocks.com/company-information/company-profile/ABOT.html"

Do While objie.Busy = True Or objie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

strdate = Range("B1").Value
eddate = Range("C1").Value
Set obj = objie.Document.getElementById("from")
obj.Value = strdate
obj.Click

Set obj = objie.Document.getElementById("to")
obj.Value = eddate
obj.Click


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

objie.Quit
End Sub
```

Below is the website Link

[WebsiteLink] https://www.khistocks.com/company-information/company-profile/ABOT.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the #from and #to fields aren't accepting manual inputs.
To work around, just open the 'datepicker' after setting the dates and click on it to execute table update.
The code below works well for me, please try:

```
Set obj = objie.document.getElementById("to")
obj.Value = eddate
obj.Focus
obj.Click

Set elements = objie.document.getElementsByClassName("ui-datepicker-current-day")

For Each oElement In elements
    oElement.Click
Next oElement
```

Comment: Thanks but my question was about to manipulate the webpage, on webpage it's not populating according to the date I'm giving, it's showing the same one month data.

Comment: Still not fetching data according to the dates , still same dates in table from Aug 29, 2018 to See 18, 2018

Comment: Even I have also tried selenium for this , but no use.

Comment: You awesome  that really worked this time , but where did you get that class name for element? "Ui-datepicker-current-date?!

Comment: Chrome developer mode. You can turn it on by hitting F12, then you can see the whole page code